# How to pass "Current build parameters" to other projects after the parameter is overwrote?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I need to use one job to trigger other jobs in jenkins, all jobs have one parameter with same name, let's call it "server_name", then I installed "Parameterized Trigger Plugin" and select "**Trigger/call builds on other projects**" and add "Current build parameters" to pass "server_name" to all sub jobs, everything works well now.

But after using groovy script to **overwrite** the root job's "server_name" value, I found only the root job's parameter is overwrote, it didn't pass the new value to sub jobs, all sub jobs are still using the default "server_name" value, could someone tell me how to resolve the issue? Thanks

Comment: Could you add groovy script that overwrites "server_name" parameter? Also are parameter values replaced in build's history (JENKINS-HOST:8080/job/JOB-NAME/BUILD-NUMBER/parameters/) ?

Comment: I use EnvInject Plugin, and select "Prepare an environment for the run", then enabled "Override Build Parameters".     The groovy script is very simple, please see below:

Comment: def envs = ['qa1', 'qa2', 'dev2']

if (binding.variables.containsKey('BUILD_CAUSE_RUNDECKCAUSE')) {
    def causes = currentBuild.getCauses()[0].toString().split(",")
    for (cause in causes) {
        if (cause.contains("http://rundeck.eng.ebcolo.com")) {
            rdline = cause
            println (rdline)
            break 
        }
    }
    for (e in envs) {
        if (rdline.toLowerCase().contains(e)) {
            println(e)
            return [server_name: e]
        }
    }
}

Comment: I have resolved the issue by using "Trigger parameterized build on other projects"